# loading everything form file body tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I am trying to load only the information in a body tag (but not including the body tag) in a file using jquery. However, as `.load()` removes the body tag, I can't find a "simple" way to do this.

I would really rather not have to but a div around everything and load that in, but rather would like a work around, preferably using `.load()`, but `.get()` or `.ajax()` solutions are welcome too.

My reason for this is I want the page I'm loading to still work as a page, but when loaded in don't want it to be effected by the tags inside the head.

Answer (score 0):

Have a html file with only the content you want to load(without body). Now,

```
$('body').load('/test_witout_body.html', function() {
alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: I still want the page to be valid (encase something breaks)

Comment: If you open and close all tags properly, the page is considered to be valid. I have tried this even in older IE versions and it works fine

Comment: if the page didn't have a body/doctype, that wouldn't be valid? I want the page I'm loading from to be valid, but only want to load in the content.